# Ruby does not recognize the "^=" operator

Tags: ruby, operator-keyword

I have ruby 1.9.2dev (2010-07-02) [i486-linux].

I know that the `^=` is a ixor operator as shown in the official documentation.

This is the output when I run the script from the shell.

```
root@desk:~/Desktop/cha03# ./cha03
./cha03:35:in `block in <main>': undefined method `^' for "\x1C":String (NoMethodError)
    from ./cha03:35:in `each_byte'
    from ./cha03:35:in `each_with_index' 
    from ./cha03:35:in `<main>'
```

And this is the line that makes the error:

```
key.each_byte.each_with_index { |b,i| key[i] ^= subkey[i % 4] }
```

Comment: Can you add an example definition of `key` and `subkey` that exhibits the problem? I strongly suspect `key` of not being a String.

Answer (score 2):

In ruby 1.9 `string[some_index]` is no longer the byte value, it will instead be a string

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :001 > '123'[2] => "3"
```

String doesnt have a ^ method, so you get the error you've described. In ruby 1.8.7 you would have got the byte's value instead and it would all have worked. I think you'll have better luck using unpack to turn the string into an array of bytes, manipulate that then put it all back together, something along the lines of

```
bytes = key.unpack('C*')
bytes.each_with_index {|b,i| ... }
key = bytes.pack('C*')
```

Answer (score 1):

extending class `String` to be able to easy `xor`-ed with another string or number
example use:

```
#irb -E binary
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :021 > "foo".xor('bar')
 => "\x04\x0E\x1D" 
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :022 > "foo".xor(1)
 => "gnn"
```

---

```
class String
  def xor x
    if x.is_a?(String)
      r = ''
      j = 0
      0.upto(self.size-1) do |i|
        r << (self[i].ord^x[j].ord).chr
        j+=1
        j=0 if j>= x.size
      end
      r
    else
      r = ''
      0.upto(self.size-1) do |i|
        r << (self[i].ord^x).chr
      end
      r
    end
  end
end
```